# How To Determine What Is Causing An App To Start At Login

Tags: startup

Every time I start my Ubuntu computer and login, a GEdit window opens immediately; this window has nothing in it.  I checked my startup applications and can't find the culprit.

I am not using the "automatically remember running application when logging out" option.

Here is my list of startup apps that are checked to run:

- Certificate and Key Storage
- Check for new hardware drivers
- desktopnova-daemon
- Disk Notifications
- GNOME Login Sound
- GSettings Data Conversion
- Indicator for DesktopNova
- Indicator-LockKeys
- Lookit Screenshot Uploader
- Network Manager
- NVIDIA X Server Settings
- Power Manager
- Print Queue Applet
- PulseAudio Sound System
- PulseAudio Soudn System KDE Routing Policy
- Remote Desktop
- Secret Storage Service
- Sound Icon
- SSH Key Agent
- Ubuntu One
- Update Notifier
- User folders update
- Visual Assistance

I'm still very new to Linux and Ubuntu, so I'm sure there might be another place I can check that I'm not aware of.

Thank you to whoever can help me figure this out; and learn from it :)

Comment: With this gedit window open - when you look at the list of running processes (via *System Monitor* or `ps aux | grep gedit`) - does the command in the list only say **gedit** or something more?

Comment: What is the output of `ls ~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session/`?

Comment: @DoR:  output is:

103b560ff9ca70bf7e130121207975368700000013830042.desktop
105c004cfff969f961130117169168061200000041410028.desktop
105c004cfff969f961130117169168124200000041410029.desktop
105c004cfff969f961130117169168179200000041410030.desktop

Comment: @arrange:

shuey     1823  0.5  0.8 173600 17140 ?        Sl   17:09   0:00 gedit --sm-client-id 103b560ff9ca70bf7e130121207975368700000013830042 --sm-client-state-file /home/shuey/.config/session-state/gedit-1301212222.desktop
shuey     2164  0.0  0.0   4012   748 pts/0    S+   17:12   0:00 grep --color=auto gedit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling the *Automatically remember running application when logging out* option in *Startup Applications* doesn't cause gnome-session to forget the "remembered" applications. To do this, delete all the files in `~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session`:

```
rm ~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session/*
```