# Review / edit startup programs rembered by "Remember Currently Running Applications"

Tags: 10.04, startup

I recently hit the "Remember Currently Running Applications" button and unchecked "Automatically remember ..." and now I seem to be stuck with a lot of stuff on startup. None of it is listed under "Startup Programs" (and what is -- Pidgin, Skype -- launches twice). Is there a way to edit or review the "Currently Running Applications" that are remembered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the applications "remembered" are stored in the following folder:

~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session

Use the file-manager to navigate to this folder - remember to use "View - Show Hidden files" to see the ".config" folder.

Use the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32928/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-an-app-to-start-at-login) if you want to remove all "remembered" applications.

Comment: For bonus kicks, what I did exactly was `vim ~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session/*` 

Then I emptied (with `:%d`) all the .desktop files I didn't want to keep, leaving slab (http://askubuntu.com/questions/37642/what-is-this-slab-that-i-am-seeing-in-my-session-file) and a couple of others in place.  Then `find ~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session/ -size 0 -exec rm {} \;` et voila. NOTE: don't run random commands unless you understand them, okay? Especially not ones with "rm" in them.