# What is this "slab" that I am seeing in my session file?

Tags: 10.04, startup, session

I'm going through the contents of `.config/gnome-settings/saved-session` per  [Review / edit startup programs rembered by "Remember Currently Running Applications"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37521/review-edit-startup-programs-rembered-by-remember-currently-running-applicatio/37533#37533) and for the most part, I know what I'm looking at: Skype, Firefox, Thunderbird, Pidgin, Compiz. There's a .desktop that launches `slab` however that is total greek to me:

```
Name=slab
Comment=Client 10569c3d37c1bbff11303905894371800000041980039 which was automatically saved
Icon=system-run
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-startup-id=10569c3d37c1bbff11303905894371800000041980039
Exec=slab --sm-config-prefix /slab-uQ6GWK/ --sm-client-id 10569c3d37c1bbff11303905894371800000041980039 --screen 0
```

I tried looking around in the Ubuntu Package Manager for a hint, but there's no package named "slab" there. So I'm wondering: what is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but did you per chance install [gnome-main-menu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-main-menu)  at some point? It was known as "the slab" and depends on libslab.

Comment: I did indeed, I'm sure that's it.