# Is there a terminal command for saving a session on 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I have tried using the dconf Editor and enabling auto-save-session-one-shot, however it did not work. I don't need it to save every time, but when I'm working on a project it would be helpful. Is there a terminal command I can execute before powering down? Thanks

Edit: I don't use hibernate because I often switch back and forth to my Windows partition to play games.

Comment: Session saving is dropped in Gnome Shell. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084389/automatically-remember-current-running-applications

Comment: You try to find alternatives in KDE or MATE.